# Can we create maps activity in Android Studio with main activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, maps

In all online tutorials they are selecting map activity while creating new project but i want to use map activity as additional feature and hence want to create project with main activity. How can i create maps activity after creating new project with main activity?

Not getting an option of creating maps activity after creating project with empty activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Right-click on app -> New -> Activity -> **Gallery**

Click on Gallery. There you will find Google Map Activity.